# Laravel - Formulário de múltiplas paginas; Melhores práticas

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Laravel aonde existirá diversos projetos de pesquisa (a validação de cada formulário é um pouco complexa).

```
Schema::create('projetos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name'); // Nome do projeto
    $table->string('view_route'); //rota do projeto
    $table->string('model_name'); //model que irá usar
    $table->string('title')->unique();
    $table->string('description');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});


<form method="POST" action="{{ action('SurveyController@insert') }}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>  
    <div class="page-1">
        <!-- Diversos Inputs aqui -->
    </div>
    <div class="page-2">
        <!-- Diversos Inputs aqui -->
    </div>
    <div class="page-3">
        <!-- Diversos Inputs aqui -->
    </div>
    <div class="page-4">
        <!-- Diversos Inputs aqui -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Irá ter apenas um `Controller` para delegar cada pesquisa.

A minha ideia é fazer um único `<form />` (com todos os `inputs` dentro) para enviar ao banco de uma vez só (será enviado somente na última página, ao clickar no botão de `finish`), a validação seria feita somente no front-end e para paginar, utilizaria um plugin (como `jquery-steps` por exemplo).
É uma boa prática colocar o nome da `Model` e a rota do `View` no banco de dados? daí, eu não precisaria criar diversos `Controllers` para cada nova pesquisa que será desenvolvida, só precisaria criar o `Model` e `View`.
por exemplo:

**SurveyController**

```
//Irá ter apenas um ``Controller`` para delegar cada pesquisa.
public function index($id)
{
    //$id é o id do projeto
    $project = Projeto::findOrFail($id);
    return view($project->view_route)->with(compact(['project']));
}

public function insert(Request $request)
{
    //não sei se vai funcionar, mas a idéia é essa:
    $project = Projeto::findOrFail($request->input('id'));
    $model = $project->model_name;
    $newModel = new $model;
    $newModel->insert(
        $request->all() //os inputs terão o mesmo nome das colunas do banco
    );
}
```

Comment: A sua pergunta está confusa, tem como melhorar?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic reformulei a pergunta...

Comment: Vários projetos de pesquisas! não é uma tabela que contem tudo isso.? eu acho problemático fazer assim! pelo fator manutenção

Comment: A parte da View é legal !!! acho funcional com aquele plugin.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic é que cada projeto vai ser diferente do outro (diferentes inputs e diferentes perguntas); uns vão ter perguntas diferentes, ou vai ter mais ou vai ter menos. Eu poderia fazer uma database com esse ``schema``: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey . mas será muito trabalhoso.

Comment: Eu acho que você tem que pensar fora da caixa, dentro de todas as possibilidades, e não ter um controller pra tudo, isso talvez cause mais problema do que solução, bom essa é minha opinião

Comment: Eu gostei da solução, claro que você terá uma certa complexidade para tratar casos específicos, mas pode fazer isso delegando a uma classe de domínio que implemente métodos padrões para suas necessidades de trato diferenciado. O que não acho seguro é a validação apenas no cliente, acredito que você também poderia gravar as regras de validação na base como faz com views e models